# Creating angular library

Tags: angular, npm, shared-libraries

I am creating some npm library using this

https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Only problem is that in folder **projects** i have some files in folder **styles**, that i want to copy to my dist folder, but when i try

```
ng build my-lib
```

Files from **styles** folder are not copied, i have tried to put them in 
**tsconfig.lib.json** like this

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "public_api.ts",
    "index.ts",
    "styles/*.*"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
}
```

But nothing is copied to dist folder, any idea, thanks

Comment: The style-files (along with the styles-folder) are automatically copied to dist as long as they are referenced in any other html- or stylesheet-files within your project-directory.

Comment: I dont want that, i need sass files not to be compiled, that i can import them in my main projects